# Laravel : if record not found then search relational model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

I am trying to find a record in `User` model , **if the record doesn't exists in `User`** model, **Then find it in `UserCompany` model with relation name `company` in `User` model.**

```
$companyUser = \App\User::whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('company_email', '=', $request->email);
})->where('email', $request->email)->get();
```

> I am getting empty set there, What am i missing.

Comment: add `with('company')->` before `whereHas` and it should works. but this just if the email is the same! If you want a `or`, you can use `orWhere` or `orWhereHas`

Comment: @SimoneCabrino No email can't be the same,It can be different, I have to search both models.

Comment: What model do you want to return in the second case? `User` or `UserCompany`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
$companyUser = \App\User::where('email', $request->email)
              ->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($request) {
                   $query->where('company_email', '=', $request->email);
                })->get();
```

Comment: I don't want to pass two variables to the view. I need to get it done with one !

Comment: @Dip this will pass only one variable. If User is not found in the first query then it will go into the if condition code

Comment: But things will be different in the view :

If record is from user then it will be `{{ $companyUser->email }}` if not  `{{ $companyUser->company_email }}`.

I don't want to check it in conditions

Comment: You just simply moved `where('email', $request->email)` to the top, Same like mine in the question.

Comment: I have added **orWhereHas** in the query.Just try it @Dip it's working now?